# How to execute linux commands from a python script

Tags: python, linux, shell

When I use the linux shell I write `module load numeca/open/61_numeca_mpi`, I press enter, the program uploads the module licence, and then I write `fine` and press enter again. I wrote a Python script which does this.

```
import os

os.system("module load numeca/open/61_numeca_mpi")
os.system("fine")
```

It uploads the module licence but then it says

```
ERROR:105: Unable to locate a modulefile for 'fine'.
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: The problem with what you tried is that `os.system` opens a new shell for each command, this means that the `fine` you sent was in a different shell then the the `module` command before it

Answer (score 1):

Try using the subprocess module:

```
import subprocess
p= subprocess.Popen(['module','load numeca/open/61_numeca_mpi"'],stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
p.stdin.write('fine')
p.communicate()[0]
p.stdin.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try executing both commands in the same shell, like this:

```
os.system("module load numeca/open/61_numeca_mpi && fine")
```